# Are all the Pokémon in the same place for all players?

Tags: google-maps-pokemon

The Google April Fool's joke this year has us hunting for Pokémon on Google maps. Are the pokemon randomly distributed for each player, or a static list?

It seems there are a few preset ones, like the ones around the Google HQ.

Comment: Lets test it. Samaurott is at Circular Quay in Sydney, Australia for me. Nearby (east) there's a Tyranitar. How about you?

Comment: I see both of those, but much closer (west) is an inkay, and more west is charmander

Comment: Yep got those as well. I'd say they're in set positions then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Almost) all Pokémon are in set locations. Note that most Pokémon appear in several places so you don't need to go to each and every place and find all of them in each place.
There are actually online lists of where to find each of them, which would obviously not work if they were in different places.

Many of the locations are also chosen with something in mind. For example, Fire-types are common around volcanoes, Flying-types like Airports, Ice-types are generally on tall mountains like Mt. Everest, Snorlax are located in Vatican City (whatever that's supposed to mean) or on roads and Pidgey (dubbed "*Bird Jesus*" in the popular *Twitch plays Pokémon*) can be found in Jerusalem.

The locations are also mostly well-known and popular places for tourists. Your starting point is one of the "PokéLabs" closest to your actual position (Europe gets CERN, USA gets the Google HQ, Japan, possibly all of Asia, gets the Tokyo Pokémon Center, and so on).

In the spirit of the real games, there is a secret 151st Pokémon (Mew), which has no set location (credit to @Kareen for pointing this out). According to different reports, it only appears after having caught all 150 other Pokémon. It's location seems to be drawn randomly from a pool of possible locations including the Bermuda triangle and the Amazon river.

Comment: Are you sure you get Zapdos? I don't have it on my PokeDex...

Comment: Sorry, I confused the nicknames there. Bird jesus is Pidgeot. There's no Zapdos.

Comment: @scenia you mean Nintendo actually acknowledged TPP as a thing?

Comment: The first 150 Pokémon are all in set locations, but the 151st Pokémon isn't.

Comment: @scenia Still, I don't have Pidgeot on my PokeDex either. I do have Pidgey there, but then again, Pidgey is one of the most common Pokemon I found. I must have caught about a dozen Pidgeys

Comment: @jerry There is no Pidgeot in this Pokédex... Maybe Scenia meant Pidgey?

Comment: @Kareen Maybe... That's what I 'm trying to confirm :)

Comment: @0xFFF1 Not necessarily Nintendo, but Google seems to. It would make sense, I mean, we're talking about "Bird Jesus" located in Jerusalem... @ the others: It was Pidgey, you're right. I actually only heard from a friend at first, but have now confirmed the exact species. It's still Bird Jesus :P